# Can you send SMS notification/message to yourself with Twilio python?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio

I just know how to send message with create method, from and to which number. What would happen if "from" and "to" number are the same? Or do I need to use a special method to receive notification?

Answer (score 1):

Python aside, it is not possible to send an SMS to the same number from which it was sent: [Error 21211](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21211).

However, it is possible to send a message to the same phone number via the same programmable SMS service provided you specify an alphanumeric sender. This means you can get around having to purchase an additional phone number.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were asking, but it tripped me up recently, so I thought I would share!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [send a message using the Twilio SMS API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) the [`From` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#from) (`from_` in the Python library) must be a Twilio number or short code that you own or a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services#send-a-message-with-copilot).

If you set the `To` number to the same as the `From` number I believe it would send a message to that number, but that number would be a Twilio number, so you'd have to receive it with a [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks). But if you are running code to send a message and running code to receive that message, you might as well cut out the middleman and just run code within your application to notify you of whatever the message would have said.

If that's now what you mean, then you can definitely set the `From` number as your Twilio number and the `To` number as your own mobile number and send yourself messages.

Unless I am misunderstanding, then I would appreciate if you could comment to correct me and I'll update my answer to help.